# Avoid vertical overflow when using KaTeX with horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css, katex

I use [KaTeX](https://katex.org/) to display equations on a webpage, and I would like to make large equations horizontally scrollable (especially on mobile). However, when I add the CSS rule

```
.katex {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

also a vertical scroll bar appears, and the equation becomes slightly scrollable vertically. So apparently the height of the contents of `.katex` are bigger than the box itself. I can adjust the size of the `.katex` box manually by adding

```
min-height: 100px;
```

however then the height of equations is not dynamically assigned anymore.

I don't understand why the `.katex`-box is apparently smaller than its content. How does that happen? As far as I see there are no CSS rules that limit the height or anything.

Here is a [minimal working example](https://jsfiddle.net/1kmyo620/1/).

Answer (score 1):

[Some recently added documentation](https://katex.org/docs/issues.html#css-customization) suggests a reasonable workaround for this behavior:

- Add an `overflow-y: hidden` rule
- Or equivalently, use `overflow: scroll hidden` (or `overflow: auto hidden`).

I've been using this workaround for a while, and haven't seen any improperly clipped math expressions. It's confusing, but seems to work.